# 4 Date Columns - Combined Field to Pick the Most Recent Date?

Tags: tableau-api

I have four columns with dates.

Column A, Column B, Column C and Column D

Each row has Column A, however depending on the data, some rows have a date entry in Column B C or D.  I want to create a new column which displays the most recent date if multiple dates are present.

Was hoping a MAX could solve it but that is limited to 2 date fields.

Any advice?

Comment: Is pivoting your data an option? https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/pivot.html That would turn your columns in rows and the max() function will work perfectly and you don't need to worry about whether a column has a value or not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there only seems to be this substandard solution -- because what if you had `n` columns:

```
max(Column A,max(Column B,max(Column C,Column D)))
```